# how to find first boot time and last shut down time of computer in a particular day?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, wmi

I need to find when the computer is started first time and shut down at last in a day.

For ex. I would have started my computer at morning 10 and multiple times i would have restarted or put on idle condition. Finally at the day end (9 PM) i would shut down the machine.

I would like to find for the last 2 weeks how long i have spent in front of my computer roughly.

Below command is giving uptime in eventlog message for a day but it is showing multiple uptime in seconds. Instead if i can get first boot time and last shut down time i can easily calculate it.

```
(get-eventlog -EntryType Information -LogName System -InstanceId 2147489661 -newest 25)
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. Personally I look for the event service startup event and stop event. then just sort for the first and last respectively. Having said that, as a general rule that is not a valid way to calculate up time since it does not account for any time that the machine is shut down during the day. Adding the actual uptimes and converting to a timespan would be better.

Comment: For @EBGreen's technique with the event logging service, you need EventID 6005 (startup) and 6006 (shutdown), but it will be quite complicated to take into account multiple restarts (I assume you sometimes need to reboot during the day) or any time you started up one day and closed down the next.  If you aren't worried about historical data, then consider creating startup/shutdown scripts that log the information to your own file (or event log), then you'll have better control of how it is recorded (hopefully making querying easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about getting the very first and last log entry for every day
provided the pc is shut down and has only one user.

This script gets the time span between first last log entry for the previous 10 days:

```
    -1..-10 | ForEach {
    $When =  (Get-Date).AddDays($_)
    $After =  Get-Date $When  -Hour 0  -Minute 0  -Second 0
    $Before = Get-Date $When  -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59
    $DayEvents =(Get-Eventlog -Entrytype Information -Logname System -After $After -Before $Before).TimeGenerated
    if($dayevents -ne $null) {
        $Span = New-Timespan -Start ($DayEvents | Select -Last 1) -End ($DayEvents | Select -First 1)
        "Your computer worked hard on {0} - for {1}:{2}:{3} hours" -F $When.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'),$Span.Hours,$Span.Minutes,$Span.Seconds
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "Holiday for your computer on {0}. It is not powered on" -F $When.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') 
        Write-host $msg -foregroundcolor green
    }
}
```

Sample Output

```
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-19 - for 12:5:22 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-18 - for 8:38:51 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-17 - for 9:25:5 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-16 - for 10:36:36 hours
Holiday for your computer on 2018-04-15. It is not powered on
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-14 - for 14:55:7 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-13 - for 13:47:32 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-12 - for 13:3:19 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-11 - for 12:35:29 hours
Your computer worked hard on 2018-04-10 - for 10:37:51 hours
```

Comment: Nice enhancement Samselvaprabu , my PC usually runs through.

Answer (score 1):

I used the previous codes to get the last boot and shutdown time on the 7 last days,

I renam the InstanceID and the TableHeaders to make the result clear :

```
0..-7 | ForEach {
$When =  (Get-Date).AddDays($_)
$After =  Get-Date $When  -Hour 0  -Minute 0  -Second 0
$Before = Get-Date $When  -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59

Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' -InstanceID 12, 13 -After $After -Before $Before -Source 'Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General'`
| Select @{Name = ’Action’; Expression = {$_.InstanceID -replace '12','Power ON' -replace '13','Power OFF'}}, @{Name = ’Date’; Expression = {$_.TimeGenerated}}`
| Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the events from the system event log. I'd probably use the kernel startup and stop times:

```
## 12 is a startup
## 13 is a shutdown
Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' `
    -InstanceID 12, 13 `
    -Source 'Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General' `
| Select InstanceID, TimeGenerated `
| sort TimeGenerated
```

I'd diff the startup time from the next found shutdown time. Since you're just asking for where to find the times, I'll stop there. You can also grab boot time from `systeminfo`.

Comment: It is showing totally 12 values the first entry start last year and latest one is 2 week back. But i shut down my system everyday. I think this is not system boot and shutdown time

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm running Windows 10. It's accurate for me. You sure you're shutting down and not putting the system to sleep?